# how to echo at the end of a loop?

Tags: shell, while-loop

**Problem :**

I have a variable which is defined inside a while loop. I build this variable and at the end I'd like to echo it. Like this :

```
function removeCarriageReturn()
{
  word=""

  echo "${1}" | while IFS= read -r -n1 char ; do
    if [ "${char}" != $"\r" ] ; then
      word="${word}${char}"
    fi
  done && echo ${word}
}
```

I don't know how to do it. If I do the echo after, word is empty because the while is like a sub shell.

Comment: What language is this supposed to be?

Comment: sorry force of habit I set wrong tag

Comment: BashFAQ #24 -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 -- is on point.

Comment: BTW, `echo ${word}` still puts the contents through string-splitting, glob expansion, etc; it's not guaranteed to print the exact contents of `word`. Much safer to use `printf '%s\n' "$word"` -- it's quotes, not curly braces, that add safety against glob expansion and string-splitting, and `echo` is deprecated -- see the POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, particularly APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Comment: BTW, you should use either `declare word` or `local word` at the top of your function; otherwise, the variable is set in global scope.

Comment: (I'd also argue against using the `function` keyword -- it's incompatible with POSIX sh function declaration syntax, but unlike other bashisms such as `$''` or `<<<`, adds no benefit in exchange for that incompatibility).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using bash? It looks like you are, based on the `function` declaration and the `$'\r'`. If so, there's a quite simple solution:

```
function removeCarriageReturn()
{
  local word

  while IFS= read -r -n1 char ; do
    if [ "${char}" != $"\r" ] ; then
      word="${word}${char}"
    fi
  done <<<"$1" && echo "$word"
}
```

Here I'm using a bash here string `<<<` to pass the value to the loop, rather than using `echo` with a pipe. It is the use of a pipe that is causing your loop to be run within a subshell.

As an aside, using braces around variables (e.g. `${word}`) can be useful in some places but doesn't actually protect you from word splitting or glob expansion. It's best to quote your variables (i.e. use `"$word"` instead). Even in a seemingly benign case such as `echo ${word}`, you may be caught out if there's a `*` within the word, for example.

Better yet, use `printf '%s\n' "$word"`, for the reasons mentioned in [Charles' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249509/how-to-echo-at-the-end-of-a-loop/31249679#comment50496736_31249509) above.

As Charles has also mentioned, you should use `local` or `declare` so that `word` is declared in a local scope.

Comment: you just solved 2 problem! I didn't know before your answer why my loops where sometimes being in subshell!! Thanks!"!

Comment: I'd suggest going as far as `printf '%s\n' "$word"` -- even `echo "$word"` won't behave consistently across platforms if `word` is `-n` or (on particularly non-compliant implementations such as bash's) `-e`).